# I want to prevent browser back button functionality in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, browser

There is a modal. When the modal is open, it should be closed when the browser back button is pressed. If there is no modal open, the browser should behave the default behavior.

Here is my code. But it is not working properly.

```
openImageMobileModal(content: any) {
    this.photoMobileModal(content);
  }
  private photoMobileModal( myModal: any) {
      this.isModalOpen = true;
      this.modalRef=this.modalService.open(myModal, {
      size: "modal-lg",
      windowClass: 'modal-lg',
      centered: true,
  });

      window.addEventListener('popstate', this.handlePopState.bind(this));
  }

  private handlePopState(event: any) {
    // Prevent the default behavior of the browser's back button
      event.preventDefault();

    // Check if the modal is open
      if (this.modalRef) {
      // Close the modal
        this.modalRef.close();
        this.modalRef = null; // Reset modal reference

      // Remove the event listener to avoid memory leaks
        window.removeEventListener('popstate', this.handlePopState.bind(this));
    }
  }
```

Comment: The event listener removal is definitely not going to work.

Comment: can you please explain?

Comment: `.bind()` generates a new function. The one you're adding is not the same as the one you're removing. You need to capture a reference to the actual function if you want to remove it later.

Comment: You'd better add a hash or a param in your URL when the modal is opened. Then on back button, the hash will be removed, but you will stay on the same page. You modal should watch the url and close itself when hash is not there anymore.

Comment: you can't modify anything about the browser's back button behavior. But you can control navigation history by way of location.assign or location.replace... (one adds to history, one does not) In short, use Pof's solution. Trigger the modal by setting location.assign to add params to the URL.  Angular will read the query params when you assign.  (it knows the hash has changed...)